# timeseries_dataset_from_array() indexing the data parameter

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, dataset, recurrent-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
int_sequence = np.arange(10)

sequence_length = 3
offset = 1 
delay = sequence_length + offset - 1

dummy_dataset = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=int_sequence[:-delay],
    targets=int_sequence[delay:],
    sequence_length=sequence_length,)


for inputs, targets in dummy_dataset:
    for i in range(inputs.shape[0]):
        print([int(x) for x in inputs[i]], int(targets[i]))
```

*Adapted from Deep Learning by Python, Chapter 10 Deep Learning for Timeseris, Auth: Chollet F.*

Using the above code, why is it necessary that `data = [:-delay]`?

Output would be as such:

```
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
[0, 1, 2] 5
[1, 2, 3] 6
[2, 3, 4] 7
```

Seems that it could be index as `data = [:-1]` to obtain the maximal number of data samples and target pairs, with the following pairs.

```
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
[0, 1, 2] 5
[1, 2, 3] 6
[2, 3, 4] 7
[3, 4, 5] 8
[4, 5, 6] 9
```